# Was my exit from Turkey recorded? If not, what do I do?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, turkey

I just exited Turkey after a three-week visit, whereby my ID was not scanned and the migration card I got on entry was not stamped - only got a stamp on the boarding pass.

Was too sleepy to think about it further, but now, back home, I wonder if my exit was actually recorded? My document info was not registered when I booked the flight, nor was my ID checked against the boarding pass when I boarded.

In case my exit wasn't recorded, whom can I contact to fix this so I'm not wrongfully flagged as an overstayer? Tried messaging the Turkish MFA, but they didn't even answer my question after three messages in simple English (instead giving totally irrelevant replies)

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: @arved Er, because I don't want to be flagged as an overstayer?

Comment: Just keep your boarding pass for the next visit and you'll do fine.

Comment: I think overstayers are just detected at the exit gate. I doubt there is big data processing all border crossings

Comment: @arved They do log entries and exits, because this time when entering from Georgia I was asked what I did in Turkey for only one day (my previous visit, which was transit)?

Comment: Please refrain from name-calling on SE. Remember, [be nice](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I e-mailed the Turkish consulate in Berlin, stating my name and document number. They called me saying that my exit had **not** been recorded.

They were somewhat surprised that I had entered on an ID card (as those from my country officially aren't accepted by Turkey, although in practice they've always been OK with mine at the border), but asked me to send a copy of it along with the migration card and stamped boarding pass. So I did, and I assume the records will now be corrected.

Comment: But aren't all EU citizens allowed to enter Turkey with an ID card?

Comment: @user59683 No http://www.mfa.gov.tr/countries-whose-citizens-are-allowed-to-enter-turkey-with-their-national-id_s.en.mfa

Comment: That's stupid.... why don't they just add all the EU countries to the list??

Comment: @user59683 Except in the case of North Cypriots and Georgians, it's essentially based on this agreement from 1957 https://rm.coe.int/CoERMPublicCommonSearchServices/DisplayDCTMContent?documentId=09000016806c507b All in all, the Turkish list roughly includes Western Europeans and Greeks, in Addition to North Cypriots and Georgians

Comment: Ooh so it has nothing to do with the European union..... I was thinking otherwise because Turkey gives you evisa on arrival if you have a visa for any schengen country. Even for people holding visas for UK, Ireland etc. So I thought they had some sort of arrangement with the EU(considering they want to join)

Comment: @user59683 Turkey is not in the EU or Schengen, i.e. not part of the freedom of movement. Being Swedish I only get to stay in Turkey for 90 days in a 180-day period without a residence permit, and a lot of EU/Schengen citizens (not me though) actually need e-visas to enter

Comment: I get that.... I thought they would be more accepting because they want to join